# Boot folder writing permission

Tags: raspbian, boot, file

I would like to write file raspbian boot folder via samba file server. But when i try to do it, raspbian doesn't allow me to writing file. How can I solve this problem. I have tried chmod command etc., but it didn't work. Could you help me if you have an idea about it. By the way, since I can only reach boot folder with windows explorer when i plug the sd card my windows computer, i want to write file boot folder.

Comment: you'll need to **install** and configure samba to allow this - as for writing to the boot partition with the sd card in a windows computer, the simple answer is **you can't**

Comment: so, is it possible that showing /home/pi (not /boot) directory when I plug an sd card to Windows computer

Comment: oh ... sorry, it's the ROOT you can't see in windows, of course you can see BOOT

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the Raspberry Pi mounts the /boot folder as root-owned because it's a VFAT partition. According to https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-auto-mount-fat32-formatted-drives-in-samba/ you can work around this by editing /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=XXX /boot vfat dmask=000,fmask=111 0 0
```

where UUID is the UUID of your /boot partition.

Note: I haven't tried this myself.